# Any decent opt-out solutions to comply with the EU Cookie Directive?

Tags: cookies

So the EU cookie law comes into effect next week and we need to make our site compliant. The problem I have is that our average order value per customer is massive meaning if we lose just 1 customer per month because they thought our site looked 'spammy' when shown a dropdown opt-in warning bar, that could lose us anywhere around £50,000 worth of business.

Does anyone know of any unobtrusive yet compliant solutions that we can use to make our site legal?

We are currently only using a couple of 3rd party tracking cookies as well as Google Analytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people are looking at the bt.com implementation of the cookie directive as instructional, and one that attempts to balance the need for better user disclosure with the impact on the user experience. You can see how it operates by clearing bt.com cookies and visiting their site as a new user:

http://bt.com

It is not clear that it strictly complies with the directive, so you need to be careful.